# Resume pagination after specific document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I'm loading user comments on my website. Initially, I only load a subset of comments and show a `Load more` button which loads the next page and **appends it to the end of the comments list**.

[image]

Loading another page works by using the usual `skip` and `limit` aggregation steps in MongoDB:

```
const aggregationResult = await ResourceCommentModel.aggregate()
    .match({
        resourceId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.resourceId),
        parentCommentId: undefined
    })
    .sort({ 'createdAt': -1 })
    .facet({
        comments: [
            { $skip: (page - 1) * pageSize },
            { $limit: pageSize },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'resourcecomments',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'parentCommentId',
                    as: 'replies',
                }
            }
        ],
        totalCount: [{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }]
    })
    .exec();
```

**Problem: If new comments have been posted in the meantime, comments from page one have been pushed to page 2, and we are loading duplicate comments (and showing them in the UI).**

[image]

One option would be to not rely on the `page` number, but instead start after the last loaded timestamp:

```
comments: [
    { $match: { createdAt: { $gt: new Date(continueAfterTimestamp) } } },
    { $limit: pageSize },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'resourcecomments',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'parentCommentId',
            as: 'replies',
        }
    }
],
```

However, there are **2 problems** with this approach:

1. Although unlikely, if two comments were posted at the exact same millisecond, one of them will not be loaded.
2. The bigger problem: I'm planning to later allow sorting comments by upvotes, and then I don't have a way to start after the last loaded document anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ObjectID instead of the timestamp. It is unique, and has a timestamp inside.

```
{ $match: { _id: { $gt: new ObjectId(continueAfterID) } } },
```

For the "bigger problem" add upvotes to the play. You gonna need an index anyway, so make it compound `{upvote:-1, _id:1}` and pass the latest upvote to the filter:

```
{ $match: { $or:[
    {$and: [{upvote: continueUpvote}, {_id: { $gt: new ObjectId(continueAfterID) } }] },
    {upvote: {$lt: continueUpvote} }
]}}
```

Or just dedup results clientside. It's trivial with react, and still easy to do with vanilla js and real DOM.

Comment: Smart, thank you. At first, I didn't want to use the `_id` as the timestamp replacement because it only has a precision of 1 second (within this one second, the order of ids can be arbitrary). But then I realized that 1 second is absolutely sufficient for a comment system.